# SQL Query - Distinct doesn't seem to filter

Tags: sql, duplicates, distinct

I'm utilizing four separate tables and i can't seem to figure out why my DISTINCT isn't filtering the results. I'm trying to get a single result for each acct.Name in this query. Regardless if i use DISTINCT or not, i get the exact same results.

```
Select DISTINCT
  acct.Name,
  inv.InvoiceNumber,
  acct.AccountNumber,
  addr.Line1,
  addr.Line2,
  addr.Line3,
  addr.City,
  addr.StateOrProvince,
  addr.postalcode
FROM InvoiceBase inv, AccountBase acct
JOIN AccountExtensionBase base 
  ON base.AccountId = acct.AccountId
JOIN CustomerAddressBase addr
  ON addr.ParentId = acct.AccountId
WHERE
  inv.AccountId=acct.AccountId And
  base.New_cocat_master = 1 And
  base.New_CompanyId = 1 And
  inv.StateCode = 0 And
  inv.Name = '2013 ' + acct.AccountNumber
ORDER by acct.Name
```

The first result i get now has the first three values (acct.Name, inv.InvoiceNumnber, acct.AccountNumber) and the rest of the columns are blank. The second row has all of the columns with the information. I'm just trying to make the acct.Name to be DISTINCT

Comment: When you say: `doubling results`, do you mean it's retrieving twice as many rows as you expect, or do there actually appear to be duplicate rows in the result set?

Answer (score 1):

**The rows are DISTINCT**

This may be confusing when you are selecting multiple strings, since there might be hidden characters/spaces. Select the length of each one of those fields and compare the so called duplicate rows.

Comment: I completely see that now. I'm doing a distinct search on every single one of those values. If i only need to be filtering by the Acct.Name would i have to create a separate select statement for that value?

Comment: You are now asking a completely new question. you need to describe it to more details including detailed expected result.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out all i had to do was add in a simple clause in the WHERE, since the address is required for a valid invoice (where to send it):

```
WHERE
  base.New_cocat_master = 1 And
  base.New_CompanyId = 1 And
  inv.StateCode = 0 And
  inv.Name = '2013 ' + acct.AccountNumber And
  addr.Line1 IS NOT NULL
```